# Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError Method...MongockTemplate.updateMulti is abstract

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, boot, mongock

I am using mongock, all migration correctly pass, bun when invoke mongoTemplate.updateMulti then throw an

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method com/github/cloudyrock/mongock/driver/mongodb/springdata/v3/decorator/impl/MongockTemplate.updateMulti(Lorg/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Query;Lorg/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Update;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/mongodb/client/result/UpdateResult; is abstract
    at com.github.cloudyrock.mongock.driver.mongodb.springdata.v3.decorator.impl.MongockTemplate.updateMulti(MongockTemplate.java)
```

```
private void updateSpecifiedCollection(MongockTemplate mongoTemplate, String collectionName) {
    Update updateQuery = Update.update("photo_width", 1920).set("photo_height", 1080);
    mongoTemplate.updateMulti(Query.query(Criteria.where("camera.serial_number")
            .is("1f3417b7-ccbf-4367-bba2-540d555ce11c").and("photo_date").gt(Instant.parse("2018-06-25T13:54:00Z"))),
        updateQuery, collectionName);
```

i am expecting it will rename specified name.

Comment: Which version are you using for Mongock and Spring data?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experimenting is that, for the Mongock version you are using, `MongockTemplate`(which is a deprecated wrapper for `MongoTemplate`) is not using the same version of MongoTemplate you are importing.

Instead of fixing the `MongockTemplate`, we highly recommend upgrading to Mongock 5.x.x, and use directly `MongoTemplate`.

Upgrading from version 4 to 5 is an easy process, but you have [this guide](https://docs.mongock.io/v5/from-version-4-to-5/index.html)